# How to use the Chrome in selenium like Protractor

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have tried to use the Chrome browser for my automation framework I can able to trigger the browser by following

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\prabhu\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

but this can be able to run on that particular System only since the driver path will be differ in all the machines. Is that possible to execute this as a generic one in all the machines? (as like protractor, here nodejs will taking care of the chrome driver path and this can be execute in any system/os without code change)

Comment: You can use selenium webdriver. By using DesiredCapabilities we can get the browser which we want

Comment: You need to set driver path into System Environment variable for every machine and just use  System variable. Thanks..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the chromedriver.exe in a folder of your project.
So that you only need to mention the relative path. That chromedriver.exe will go wherever the project folder goes.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "properties/chromedriver.exe");
```

[image]